# The grammar of "taking a shower"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage

I often hear a particular sentence about taking a shower.

> 私がシャワーをしています。

Is this the correct way to say "I am taking a shower"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 私はシャワーを浴びています。-I'm taking a shower

浴びる is the correct verb used to mean "to shower"